# Command to multiply all values in a list against one another?

Tags: awk

I have a data list `data.txt` that look something like the following:

```
Sample A
   12 
   0
   29
   238
   0
   4
```

Basically it is a biological sample (single column) and the expression of certain genes (320+ rows). I'd like multiply each of the values on each row against each other, so that I get an `output.txt` something along the lines of this:

```
-      -    -      -    -   -
0      -    -      -    -   -
348    0    -      -    -   -
2856   0    82824  -    -   -
0      0    0      0    -   -
48     0    116    952  0   -
```

I'm currently just doing it manually on excel which is a pain (I'm a biologist and am not too good with UNIX or coding in general). Is there any way I could do this with `awk` (or some other command) instead?

Also, I actually have ~300 samples (i.e. 300 separate `data.txt` files), it would be even better if I could run one script for a `data.txt` file containing all 300 samples (i.e. 300 columns, 320 rows, and values for each column on each row) and get 300 separate `output.txt` files for each sample (column).

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually that hard in `awk`, for example you could slurp the whole file into a (1d) array, and then do a double loop e.g. for a single data file:

```
awk '
  NR > 1 {
    x[NR-1] = $1;
  }
  END {
    for (i=1; ;i++) {
      if (!(i in x))
        break;
      for (j=1; ;j++) {
        if (!(j in x))
          break;
        if (j < i)
          printf "%-6d", x[j]*x[i];
        else
          printf "%-6s", "-";
      }
      printf "\n";
    }
  }
  ' data.txt
```

**Note that if you don't insist on filling the upper triangle with dashes, you can process lines much more simply on the fly**, i.e. without loading the whole file:

```
awk '
  NR > 1 {
    x[NR-1] = $1;
    for (j=1;j<NR-1;j++)
      printf "%-6d", $1*x[j];
    printf "%-6s\n", "-";
  }
  ' data.txt
-
0     -
348   0     -
2856  0     6902  -
0     0     0     0     -
48    0     116   952   0     -
```

Such an approach may provide a benefit (in terms of memory usage) if your datasets are large.

Processing multiple file arguments needs a bit of adjustment - if you have GNU awk you can make use of the `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` rules e.g.

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE {
    delete x;
  }
  FNR > 1 {
    x[FNR-1] = $1;
    next;
  }
  ENDFILE {
    n = length(x);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
      for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {
        if (j < i)
          printf "%-6d", x[j]*x[i];
        else
          printf "%-6s", "-";
      }
      printf "\n";
    }
    printf "\n";
  }
  ' data1.txt data2.txt
```

If you don't have `gawk` you can simulate the BEGINFILE/ENDFILE by checking when FNR rolls back to 1.

---

If your datasets are large however, I'd suggest using something that's built for matrix operations, such as GNU `octave` (basically you seem to want the lower triangle of the product, correct?)

You can either do it in an interactive octave interpreter, or in 'batch' mode like so:

```
$ octave -q << 'EOF'
> x = textread('data.txt', '%f', 'headerlines', 1);
> M = tril(x * x', -1);
> disp(M);
> EOF
      0      0      0      0      0      0
      0      0      0      0      0      0
    348      0      0      0      0      0
   2856      0   6902      0      0      0
      0      0      0      0      0      0
     48      0    116    952      0      0
```

Depending on your exact output requirements you can use the simple `save` or `dlmwrite` functions to write `M` to a file, or `fprintf` if you want really fine grained output format control. If you want the upper triangle zeros replaced by dashes, you will probably need to look at cell arrays.

Answer (score -1):

There is no single program which performs this specific task, so some (beginner level) coding is needed.

Awk is not particularly suitable as a programming language even if it might be possible to write an awk script for this task. Perl might be a better language for this job, but any general purpose programming or scripting language should do.
As you're not into coding, you will probably have to find someone willing to write a program for you, and leave the choice of language to them (unless they're proposing something that requires disproportionate setup effort.)

As far as I know, answers on SE are not supposed to contain complete code for specific tasks, but if someone posts such code, you might prefer their answer :-)